# scraping a specific wikipedia table using python

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, css-selectors

while trying to scrape the Tesla wikipedia page, I wanted to scrape the finnces table at the last. while trying the same with the table class in my code it is scraping almost every table on that page. can some one please help me to only scrape the finance table. following is my code;

```
start_url='https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tesla,_Inc.'
download_page=requests.get(start_url)
soup=BeautifulSoup(download_page.text)
with open ('download.html', 'w', encoding="utf-8") as file:
file.write(soup.prettify())
fullsales_table=soup.select('table.wikitable')[0]
print(fullsales_table)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try `pandas`.

Here's how:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

page = requests.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tesla,_Inc.").text
df = pd.read_html(page, flavor="bs4")[7]
print(df)
df.to_csv("tesla_revenue.csv", index=False)
```

This prints (and saves the table to a .csv file):

```
         Year  Revenue(mil. USD)  ... Total assets(mil. USD)  Employees
0   2009[463]                112  ...                    130        NaN
1   2010[463]                117  ...                    386      899.0
2   2011[464]                204  ...                    713     1417.0
3   2012[465]                413  ...                   1114     2914.0
4   2013[466]               2013  ...                   2417     5859.0
5   2014[467]               3198  ...                   5831    10161.0
6   2015[468]               4046  ...                   8068    13058.0
7   2016[469]               7000  ...                  22664    17782.0
8   2017[470]              11759  ...                  28655    37543.0
9   2018[471]              21461  ...                  29740    48817.0
10    2019[3]              24578  ...                  34309    48016.0

[11 rows x 5 columns]
```